# Using Rails partial breaks document tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

For some reason when I use a partial for the  content in my Rails app, my HTML document tree breaks and the head elements spill over the body element. I've boiled this down to a very simple example:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/head' %>
  </head>
  <body id="test-id">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app/views/shared/head.html.erb**:

```
<title>Test Title</title>
```

**result**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head> 
  <body>
    <title>Test Title</title>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the id attribute on  was lost and the  element is not where it should be.

Has anybody seen anything like this or can provide tips for debugging?

I'm running:

- OSX 10.8.3
- ruby-1.9.3-p392
- rails 3.2.11 / WEBrick
- Spree 1.1.4 (although I've stripped out anything that Spree might affect)

Comment: Are you looking at an HTML DOM inspector like Firebug or the right-click/inspect element functionality in Chrome, or are you viewing raw source?  Those inspectors try to do formatting for you, and if there is something off about the parsing they can mess it up.  If you view the raw source (right click -> view page source) you can see exactly what the browser sees, and that might make the problem immediately clear.

Comment: @ScottS, what's under 'render' is above is exactly what the browser is getting. I've modified the whitespace, however, so that it's more legible for SO.

Comment: Hmm. I've never seen rails parse and change the output of a layout like that, but then I've used 3.2 very little.  One thing I notice is that the layout has no `<%= yield %>` statement. I wouldn't expect this to be a problem, but maybe it could cause unexpected behavior.  You might try removing embedded code and outputting straight HTML, and see how that works.

Comment: @ScottS, yield didn't have an effect on the bug so I remove it for simplicity. What do you mean removing the embedded code? Are you referring to the render partial call? Replacing the content of render partial with the contents of _head.html.erb causes the bug to go away. Something is happening in that render call.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had Deface running in the background which was causing an error which was mangling my `<head>`.

If anybody is running Spree and sees weird issues with their templating, first look at the Rails logs for Deface errors and check your libxml version. If it's > 2.8.0 you may need to downgrade. More info [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/2633).